# Difficulties (unexplained error message) when plotting contour

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Trying to plot the following:

[image]

Using this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{math}     % defining sinc(x).
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
         xlabel = $k$,
         ylabel = $E(k)$,
         title = {Periodic Brillouin zone},
         xmin = -3.5*pi, xmax = 3.5*pi,
         ]

        \tikzmath{
            function sinc(\x) {
                if abs(\x) < 0.001 then {
                            return 1.0;
                        } else {
                            return sin(\x r)/\x;
                        };
                };
        } 

        \addplot3[
        domain = -3*pi : 3*pi, 
        domain y = 0.1 : 3.5,
        contour gnuplot = {levels = {0}, labels=false,},
        samples = 99, 
        samples y = 99,
        ] { cos(x) - 5*sinc( 5.12*sqrt(y) ) - cos( 5.12*sqrt(y) ) };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But I'm getting this error message:

> Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
> Y
>   l.31 ...c( 5.12*sqrt(y) ) - cos( 5.12*sqrt(y) ) };

that I can't decode. What am I doing wrong?

---

NB: I've tried using `deg(x)`(multiplying by `pi`) on the function arguments.

The first plot is made using the following MATLAB code:

```
[X, Y] = meshgrid(linspace(-3*pi, 3*pi, 99), linspace(0.1,  3.5, 99));
Z = cos(X) - ( 5*pi*sinc( 5.12 * sqrt(Y) / pi ) ) - cos( 5.12 * sqrt(Y) ); 
contour(X, Y, Z, [0,0]);  
for i = 1 : 3
  line( i * [pi, pi], [0, 3.5], 'color', 'k', 'linestyle', '--');  
  line( i * [-pi, -pi], [0, 3.5], 'color', 'k', 'linestyle', '--');    
end 

xlabel('k')
xlim( [ -(N+0.5)*pi, (N+0.5)*pi ] )
set (gca, 'xtick', [-3*pi  -2*pi  -pi 0  pi 2*pi 3*pi]) 
set (gca, 'xticklabel', {'-3\pi/a','-2\pi/a','-\pi/a','0','\pi/a','2\pi/a','3\pi/a',}) 
ylabel('E(k)')
```

[Related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268120/pgf-plot-color-map-contour-plot-from-matrix-data)

---

Comment: Instead of using `\tikzmath` you could add `/pgf/declare function={sinc(\x) = ifthenelse(abs(\x) < 0.001, 1.0, sin(\x r)/\x);}` to the `\pgfplotsset` options. But this gives a strange result. Are you sure the function is right?

Comment: There are a few things I do not understand. The desired plot looks just like a set of shifted sine and cosine functions with different amplitudes. What is the role of `sinc` here? And wouldn't you have to adjust the view if you use a 3D plot to get the contours?

Comment: @marmot I've updated the question and included the code that produced the above plot. I hope it will cover the role of `sinc`. Regarding the view, it will is either adjusting the 3D plot or finding a way of plotting only the slice, Z = 0, as a 2D plot.

Comment: I have never used MatLab. But when I look at that code, I see that the `X`-dependence of `Z` is just a cosine. Therefore, it is clear that the `X`-dependence of contours will also be cosines, and the role of the `sinc` is just to determine the distance between the cosines and their amplitudes. I'd like to argue that it will be much simpler to just use this and then do three ordinary trigonometric plots with the appropriate shifts and amplitudes.

Comment: @marmot You are probably right. I will do either that or generate the data from MATLAB, save it in a file and plot it directly from there.

Comment: You could also use pgfplots to compute the shifts and amplitudes, I guess. I am also not saying that the contour plot will necessarily fail. I just do not know what the MatLab code does precisely, i.e. how the contours are defined in detail.

Comment: @marmot `meshgrid` performs a Cartesian product from the two input row vectors that results in a 2D lattice. `Z` is a height (value of the function) on every point on that 2D lattice; or something similar to this. :)

Comment: Yes. But my question is much simpler: which contours are shown here? `cos(x) - 5*sinc( 5.12*sqrt(y) ) - cos( 5.12*sqrt(y) ) ==0`?

Comment: Only those for single height z = 0. (third argument in `contour`, `[ 0 0 ]` -scpefies single height)